Are there any performance impacts to always having --expose-gc on in Node?
To use --logHeapUsage to debug memory leaks in Jest you need to enable the node flag --expose-gc e.g:
node --expose-gc ./node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand --logHeapUsage

A colleague of mine believes that he is getting better memory performance when passing the --expose-gc flag and running tests normally (i.e. not testing for leaks):
node --expose-gc ./node_modules/.bin/jest

He has opted to pass this flag by default when running Jest tests as part of the CI/CD pipeline. I can't see how or why the flag being "on" would have any benefit and if it did why node wouldn't enable the functionality default.
Can anybody tell me if it could be possible that the flag may be improving memory performance? And if leaving it on for our CI/CD pipeline might have any negative impact?
